# IOS INAPP Purchase restore transaction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I AM a Beginner in ios, implementing in app purchase fo the first time

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    SKPaymentTransaction *temp;
    SKPaymentTransaction *transaction;
    for (transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

                    [self restoreTransaction:transaction];               

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

the parameter "transactions" has 6 Objects while restoring hence while testing in sandbox enviorment the restoreTransaction function is called six times and the pop up message i.e UIALertView is shown six times .

i want to show the POP UP only once.

Please Suggest me some solution Friends.